# If 'cc-sub-header-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 10 version and while running unit testcases facing this error:

> If 'cc-sub-header-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this
> module.
> If 'cc-sub-header-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the
> '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'

Actually added 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to '@NgModule.schemas', but still this error occurs.

My code:
Module.ts:

> ```
>    '@NgModule({
>         schemas: [
>          CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
>         ],'
> ```

Error:

> Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Windows 10) ERROR: ''cc-sub-header' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'cc-sub-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'cc-sub-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the >'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
>    Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Windows 10): Executed 117 of 190 SUCCESS (0 secs / 2.545 secs)
>    Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Windows 10): Executed 117 of 190 SUCCESS (0 secs / 2.545 secs)
>    Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Windows 10) ERROR: ''cc-sub-header' is not a known element:
>    Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Windows 10) ERROR: ''cc-sub-header-title' is not a known >element:
> 3. If 'cc-sub-header-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this >module.
> 4. If 'cc-sub-header-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'

Could I get any solution?
Thanks in Advance..!!